# Erro: JSONException: End of input at character 0, ao enviar informações do Android para um WebService PHP

Tags: php, android, utf-8, volley

Estou enviando informações do Android para um WebService PHP através da lib Volley.
Tudo funciona perfeitamente, exceto com caracteres especiais.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("nome", "áàâãõóòúç");
```

Se o nome for igual a - `nome = Maria das Graças` por exemplo, ele dá-me esse erro:

**Saída de erro:**

> W/System.err: **org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of**
>   W/System.err: at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)   > W/System.err: at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
>   W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:155)
>   W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:172)
>   W/System.err: at JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(CustomJsonObjectRequest.java:58)
>   W/System.err: at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:125)
>   E/Volley: [8220] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:130)

No PHP tive o mesmo problema no começo e resolvi usando a função `utf8_encoder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa codificar antes de enviar alguma *string* com caracteres especiais através do seu `JSON`.

Experimente utilizando a classe [`URLEncoder`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html), algo assim:

```
String nome = URLEncoder.encode("áàâãõóòúç", "utf-8");
```