# Android, PHP e HttpURLConnection - Enviar mensagem para o PHP com UTF-8

Tags: php, java, android, utf-8

Senhores, muito bom dia/tarde/noite!

Estou tendo problemas com acentuação de palavras.
O back-end do meu sistema funciona em PHP conversando com um app Android. Quando faço o envio de mensagem do App para o server PHP funciona normalmente, e o PHP responde o esperado, porém se a mensagem enviada ao PHP incluir caracteres com acento o App apresenta erro e para.

Já pesquisei é claro, porém a grande parte das pessoas estão utilizando HttpClient e estou utilizando HttpURLConnection.

Já tentei incluir uma linha dizendo que RequestProperty é UTF-8, mas não adiantou.

Segue classe de Conexão que estou utilizando.

```
package Conexao;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by billy on 21/05/2016.
 */
public class Conexao {

    private static Conexao instancia;
    public static String urlString;

    private Conexao() {
        //nothing
    }

    public static Conexao getInstancia() {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new Conexao();
        }
        return instancia;
    }

    public static JSONArray executePost(JSONObject json) {

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("contentType", "application/json");

            conn.connect();

            conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes(json.toString());

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Erro ", e.toString());
        }

        Log.i("Resposta: ", jsonArray.toString());

        return jsonArray;
    }

}
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Senhores, assim como solicitado, segue o logcat:

```
09-22 20:01:39.959 25838-25838/? E/Zygote: v2
09-22 20:01:39.969 25838-25838/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-22 20:02:06.999 25838-26110/br.com.infogruposi.sct E/Erro: org.json.JSONException: Value Nenhum of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
09-22 20:02:07.019 25838-26110/br.com.infogruposi.sct E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
                                                                        Process: br.com.infogruposi.sct, PID: 25838
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONArray.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at Conexao.Conexao.executePost(Conexao.java:68)
                                                                            at br.com.infogruposi.sct.ActAbreChamadoUsu$JSONTransmitter.doInBackground(ActAbreChamadoUsu.java:47)
                                                                            at br.com.infogruposi.sct.ActAbreChamadoUsu$JSONTransmitter.doInBackground(ActAbreChamadoUsu.java:42)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Senhores, estou fazendo testes e o seguinte trecho eu retirei do meu debug:

```
json = {JSONObject@18906} "{"cha_gru_codigo":"1","cha_pes_usuario":"3","cha_solicitacao":"zé","cha_des_texto":"zinho","classe":"chamado","acao":"usuAbrirChamado"}"
jsonArray = null
url = {URL@18958} "http://www.solusinformatica.890m.com/SCT/SCT/facade/Facade.php"
conn = {HttpURLConnectionImpl@18961} "com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://www.solusinformatica.890m.com/SCT/SCT/facade/Facade.php"
wr = {DataOutputStream@18978} 
is = {RealBufferedSource$1@18992} "buffer(com.android.okio.GzipSource@2be6139).inputStream()"
streamReader = {BufferedReader@18997} 
responseStrBuilder = {StringBuilder@19002} ""
inputStr = {String@19007} "Nenhum comando selecionado - <pre>null</pre>"
```

Esse ultimo campo inputStr é a variável que recebeu a resposta do Backend e o campo entre as tags pre, com valor null é o que o backend recebeu do App Android, ou seja, quando a mensagem possui acento o backend não recebe os dados, creio eu porque o Android simplesmente não os envia.

Tentei aplicar a solução descrita na postagem:

[Erro: JSONException: End of input at character 0, ao enviar informações do Android para um WebService PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109940/erro-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-ao-enviar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-andro?rq=1)

O App desta vez enviou a mensagem, mas o PHP a recebeu assim:
zé = z%C3%A9

Comment: Qual o erro aparece no logcat quando ele para?

Comment: Me perdoem, amigos, o erro é quando o App tenta enviar mensagem com acento para o PHP. Simplesmente a mensagem não sai do App.
Quanto ao erro, vou precisar fazer isso hoje à noite quando estiver em casa, pois já não lembro. Estou tentando resolver isso há tanto tempo que já havia desistido.

Comment: @BilllyJow Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português!! Edite sua pergunta com essa informação nova para facilitar aos próximos que lerem sua duvida!

Comment: Fiz as alterações sugeridas e, caso seja necessário, posso também postar a classe que controla a view que recebe os dados do usuário.

Comment: Esse "Nenhum" na quarta linha é proveniente do PHP que responde "Nenhum comando selecionado" quando o front não envia as informações necessárias para o Facade.

Comment: Hó, e agora, quem poderá me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Código Java no Android App:

```
String solicitacao = URLEncoder.encode(txSolicitacao.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
String descricao = URLEncoder.encode(txDescricao.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Código PHP no Backend:

```
$solicitacao = urldecode(rawurldecode($arrayJson["cha_solicitacao"]));
$descricao = urldecode(rawurldecode($arrayJson["cha_des_texto"]));
```

urldecode() = converte o sinal de + para espaços. Se não usar este comando, a string segue desta forma:

aqui+vai+um+exemplo

O problema é que o sinal de "+" sempre será convertido para espaço.

Neste caso, creio que a melhor opção seja enviar character entities para que não tenham caracteres acentuados na String. Ao receber a String jSon, o PHP poderá fazer um parser e substituir os character entities para os devidos caracteres especiais, para que seja possível gravar em banco.